# Pinging Result between A & B KVM guests in same subnet

Tags: ubuntu, kvm, ping

I have a Ubuntu 20.04 KVM host running with a number of web and application VM guests.  Suddenly, there is 1 web proxy server can't be connected.
NOTE: there is a network team to manage the network

I try to ping from web proxy server to all other machines at KVM management console.  It works.
192.168.11.61 (proxy) -> 192.168.11.60 (Host), 192.168.11.62 (app1), 192.168.11.63 (app2)
REMARK: in order to troubleshoot, I disable ufw for all guests and the host.

Then, I try to ping 192.168.11.61 (proxy) from all of the above.  None of them is working.

**Interesting Findings**
Then, I try to ping 192.168.11.61 from 192.168.11.62.  Meanwhile, I ping to ping 192.168.11.62 from 192.168.11.61. At this time, both of them are pinging each other with reply to each other.  Once I stop the ping action from 192.168.11.62, again the 192.168.11.61 cannot be reached.

For the above scenario, I have never seen it. The network team is saying that it is likely a problem of my KVM & firewall settings.

** Additional Notes **

1. KVM Host - with 2 NIC bonding (CISCO - LACP)
2. KVM Host - bridged network
3. all KVM guests are sharing the same structure of the netplan file.
4. the machines are not changed with any network settings

Answer (score 0):

Verify the netmasks are correct on each server and that the MTU settings are correct for the network segment.  I had a similar problem one time where the MTU on one host was 1500 and the other was 9000.  Once I made them both 9000, all was well.